# Alternative to eval() when caching and displaying generated PHP pages

Tags: php, caching, eval

I've worked on a CMS which would use Smarty to build the content pages as PHP files, then save them to disc so all subsequent views of the same page could bypass the generation phase, keeping DB load and page loading times down.  These pages would be completely standalone and not have to run in the context of another script.

The problem was the instance where a user first visited a page that wasn't cached, they'd still have to be displayed the generated content.  I was hoping I could save my generated file, then include() it, but filesystem latency meant that this wasn't an option.

The only solution I could find was using eval() to run the generated string after it was generated and saved to disc.  While this works, it's not nice to have to debug in, so I'd be very interested in finding an alternative.

Is there some method I could use other than eval in the above case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your scenario, I do not think there is an alternative.

As for the debugging part, you could always write it to disc and `include` it for the development to test / fix it up that way and then when you have the bugs worked out, switch it over to `eval`.

Not knowing your system, I will not second guess that you know it better than I do, but it seems like a lot of effort, especially since that the above scenario will only happen once per page...ever. I would just say is it really worth it for that one instance to display the initial page through `eval` and why could you not be the initial user to generate the pages?

Comment: You're right of course, eval does only get run the first time since the page was last uncached, I just have a rather strong aversion to eval and would much rather find an alternative way of running the generated page.

Comment: You can replace PHP keys of variable and replace it. Such as if you store variables into $view_data = array('title' => 'MyTitle') for rendering you can use into function as: function render($file, $data) { include $file; foreach ($data as $k => $v) { $$k = $v; #look at $$k }. Hope this someone to helps! You don't need eval if you not preferred caching, ob_handler etc...